# How to Redirect in PHP to same page, but without certain parameters?

Tags: php

Say my visitor arrive to:

`mydomain.com/nice-url/?p1=a&p2=b`

I want them to be redirected to:

`mydomain.com/nice-url/?p1=a`

(probably with `header("Location:`)

So I want to strip of the `p2=b` string.

Since this is just an example, and there might be many other parameters, I'm looking for smartest solution, including ways to:

1. Strip anything that starts with `p2`.
2. Strip anything that doesn't start with `p1`

Keep in mind too that `nice-url` also can be various things such as:

`name-number-one`, `name-number-two`, etc.

Also, I don't look for `.htaccess` solution, since I want to store in a session the values of the stripped parameters.

Comment: `parse_url` and then build if again

Comment: I don't know how to write such code succesfully :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested you can use `parse_url` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)). Here's a litte bit more generic way than hanshenrik posted. It uses a slightly modified of `unparse_url` found in the [documentation's](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) comments (the `$query` line is trimmed of `&`) and some regex:

```
<?
function unparse_url($parsed_url) {
  $scheme   = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' : '';
  $host     = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : '';
  $port     = isset($parsed_url['port']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['port'] : '';
  $user     = isset($parsed_url['user']) ? $parsed_url['user'] : '';
  $pass     = isset($parsed_url['pass']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['pass']  : '';
  $pass     = ($user || $pass) ? "$pass@" : '';
  $path     = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : '';
  $query    = isset($parsed_url['query']) ? '?' . trim($parsed_url['query'], '&') : '';
  $fragment = isset($parsed_url['fragment']) ? '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';
  return "$scheme$user$pass$host$port$path$query$fragment";
}

function strip_query($url, $query_to_strip) {
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  $parsed['query'] = preg_replace('/(^|&)'.$query_to_strip.'[^&]*/', '', $parsed['query']);
  return unparse_url($parsed);
}

function keep_only_query($url, $query_to_keep) {
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  $parsed['query'] = preg_replace('/(^|&)(?!'.$query_to_keep.')[^&]*/', '', $parsed['query']);
  return unparse_url($parsed);
}

$url = 'mydomain.com/nice-url/?p1=a&p2=b';

# or for request url
# $url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

# "Strip anything that starts with p2"
var_dump(strip_query($url, 'p2'));
# --> string(27) "mydomain.com/nice-url/?p1=a"

# "Strip anything that doesn't start with p1"
var_dump(keep_only_query($url, 'p1'));
# --> string(27) "mydomain.com/nice-url/?p1=a"

# redirect
$new_url = strip_query($url, 'p2')); # or whatever query you want to strip/keep
header("Location: $new_url");
```

I hope the `keep_only_query` regex is complete and working for all urls you encounter, but that's my first shot.

---

Maybe the regex is overkill (didn't do any benchmarks), so here is a version of both functions without regex but with `parse_str` and `http_build_query` (as proposed by hanshendrik).

```
function strip_query($url, $query_to_strip) {
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  parse_str($parsed['query'], $query);
  unset($query[$query_to_strip]);
  $parsed['query'] = http_build_query($query);
  return unparse_url($parsed);
}

function keep_only_query($url, $query_to_keep) {
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  parse_str($parsed['query'], $query);
  foreach($query as $query_key => $query_val) {
    if($query_key != $query_to_keep) unset($query[$query_key]);
  }
  $parsed['query'] = http_build_query($query);
  return unparse_url($parsed);
}
```

**Attention:** Opposed to the regex version this only works on parameters with **exactly** the name (eg `p1`, `p2`), whereas the regex version works on names **beginning with** the name (eg `p1=...`, `p2=...`, but also `p1something=...`, `p2_whatever=...`). Don't know if this was the intention by the wording of the question, but that is how I understand it first:

> 1. Strip anything that **starts with** ...

Of course the bottom version could be extended to compare beginnings of query keys, too ... with a regex ;-) (or `substr`)

---

And finally a version without any *weird regexes* but with `substr`, checking the beginning of the keys as intended by OP.

```
function strip_query($url, $query_to_strip) {
  $len = strlen($query_to_strip);
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  parse_str($parsed['query'], $query);
  foreach($query as $query_key => $query_val) {
    if(substr($query_key, 0, $len) == $query_to_strip) unset($query[$query_key]);
  }
  $parsed['query'] = http_build_query($query);
  return unparse_url($parsed);
}

function keep_only_query($url, $query_to_keep) {
  $len = strlen($query_to_keep);
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  parse_str($parsed['query'], $query);
  foreach($query as $query_key => $query_val) {
    if(substr($query_key, 0, $len) != $query_to_keep) unset($query[$query_key]);
  }
  $parsed['query'] = http_build_query($query);
  return unparse_url($parsed);
}
```

Comment: but why `$url = 'mydomain.com/nice-url/?p1=a&p2=b';`? The idea is that I'm looking for a code that is independent, a code that can also be used on `yourdomain.com/another-nice-url` without touching anything

Comment: You mean to get the current url? `$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";`

Comment: Yeah. though this code doesn't work, I get a `string(28) "tested-domain.com/tested-page.php?p1=a" string(28) "tested-domain.com/tested-page.php?p1=a"` Error

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Both `var_dump` output these strings. You only need the functions in your script and use them where you need them.

Comment: I added the redirect header. Try to understand the code and use it. This is no copy and paste solution.

Comment: i trust parse_str more than your regex...  
function strip_query($url, $query_to_strip) {
  $parsed = parse_url($url);
  parse_str($parsed['query'],$strparsed);
  unset($strparsed[$query_to_strip]);
  $parsed['query'] = http_build_query($strparsed);
  return unparse_url($parsed);
}

Comment: Right, maybe regex was overkill - I added both functions with `parse_str` and `http_build_query` as you proposed.

Comment: Thanks @Markus this is working, added another piece of code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155637/how-to-check-for-existence-of-paramater-in-url) to avoid a redirect loop. I do need it for anything that starts with `p2`, including `p2a` for example, so I suppose that I can use only your first method, and this is best practice for this?

Comment: I added a version without any regexes but checking the beginning of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

i guess this should work: get the original url with  $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] , parse the url with parse_url / parse_str , then remove whatever data you don't want with unset() , then rebuild the url with http_build_query, example:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8');
$urlinfo=parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
var_dump($urlinfo);
$query=isset($urlinfo['query'])?$urlinfo['query']:'';
parse_str($query,$queryinfo);
var_dump($queryinfo);
unset($queryinfo['p2']);
var_dump($queryinfo);
$newurl=$urlinfo['path'].'?'.http_build_query($queryinfo);
var_dump($newurl);
```

edit: and to finish it, a 301/302 header redirect

```
header("Location: ".$newurl,TRUE,302);
```

where 301 means "moved permanently" and 302 means "moved temporarily"

edit 2: the meaning of 302 is slightly more complicated, you can read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

Comment: I'm getting this error message: `array(2) { ["path"]=> string(11) "/test.php" ["query"]=> string(4) "p2=a" } array(1) { ["p2"]=> string(1) "a" } array(0) { } string(12) "/test.php?"`

Comment: @rockyraw yes that worked, didn't it? you only had 1 variable in your GET, which was "p2"=>"a" ... add more variables and you'll see only p2 getting removed

Answer (score -2):

You probably want something like this:

```
if (count($_GET) > 1 || !$_GET['p1']) {
    header ("location: mydomain.com/nice-url/?p1=a");
}
```

Comment: no, the code needs to be fully dynamic, no constant values such as `mydomain`, `nice-url` `a`