# How to check for existence of parameter in url?

Tags: php

I want to output a message,
whenever the url includes any parameter that start with `p2`, for example in all the following instances:

`example.com/?p2=hello`

`example.com/?p2foo=hello`

`example.com/?p2`

`example.com/?p2=`

I've tried:

```
if (!empty($GET['p2'])) {
    echo "a parameter that starts with p2 , is showing in your url address";

} else {
    echo "not showing";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check query string (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599193/check-query-string-php)

Answer (score 3):

this should cover all your cases

```
$filtered = array_filter(array_keys($_GET), function($k) {
    return strpos($k, 'p2') === 0;
});

if ( !empty($filtered) ) {
    echo 'a paramater that starts with p2 , is showing in your url address';
}
else {
    echo 'not showing';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the `$_GET` array and add a condition for the key to start with `p2` when matching do what you need to do.

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    if (substr($key, 0, 2) === "p2"){
        // do your thing
        print $value;
    }
}
```

`substr($key,0,2)` takes the first two characters from the string

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (isset($GET['p2'])) {
echo "a paramater that starts with p2 , is showing in your url address";

} else {
echo "not showing";
}
```

Comment: he actualy whants to catch domain.com/?p2foo=hello your example does not do that

Comment: doesn't work... it returns the `else`, even for `p2=` values

Comment: also btw isset($GET['p2']) && $GET['p2'] is identical to !empty($_GET['p2'])

Answer (score 0):

fastest way is

```
if(preg_match("/(^|\|)p2/",implode("|",array_keys($_GET)))){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, it always returns the if condition, even for `?a=something`

Comment: this also catches `ap2`, i need it to catch only `p2a` :)

Comment: true that, I already upvoted @danjam for his answer, but in case anyone is looking for a one liner I updated my answer